# How to handle request for same seats in BookMyShow like application

Tags: web, architecture, system-design

I came across this question in one of my interview.
if I have application like BookMyShow and I want to handle case when multiple requests come for same seat?
Also what database I should choose like SQL or nosql ?
How to handle request during high peak time.
Any help will be greatfull.

Comment: at database level there's a thing called concurrency control. Try exploring that. Let us know if you find the solution. Multi threading could be another way out. And by the way  nosql dbs like redis and mongo have special provisions for such situations especially in terms of speed.

Answer (score 0):

Using First in first out (FIFO) concept. it not depends upon you database so, you can use any database. and you will handle the large number of request using the Queue concept such like RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

A standard solutions for this sort of problems are

- to handle multiple requests to one seat just create a lock for some period of time
- in this case I would prefer sql db instead of nosql due to ACID and transaction locking levels
- handling request during high peak time could be done by collecting other request into first in first out as it was mentioned above